# Image rendering issues with testing email Specifically with ios. What do?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-client

My job is to test emails before they launch to ensure all bugs are fixed for our clients. I test them in Email-On-Acid, (software that mimics what the email will look like for various email clients,) before sending them off for more direct tests with Constant Contact.

I've been running into this issue only within the past couple of weeks. I haven't had these issues before. Some images are fully rendering and some are not, even within the same client test. Some images are omitted completely while others just preview as broken with the alt text, even within the same client test. The issue seems to be consistent between all apple/ios products and services (i.e. all ipads and iphones, apple mail, etc.)

What I've tried:

- All images are directly linked to our server I've applied mso 9 fixes
  to the  that relate to pngs
- All end tags are closed
- I've limited the number of clients email-on-acid will render at a time,
  but the issue is still there
- CSS is inline on almost everything
- I don't think it has to do with images within nested tables

```css
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/* Linked Styles */
    body { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; background:#e3e3e3; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none }
    a { color:#ff0000; text-decoration:none }
    .footer-text a { color:#000001; text-decoration:none }
    .text-2 a { color:#030303; text-decoration:none }
    .text-w a { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none }
    .h3 a { color:#384e73; text-decoration:none }
    p { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important } 
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */ }
    .mcnPreviewText { display: none !important; }
    .text-button { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none }
    /* Mobile styles */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        u + .body .gwfw { width:100% !important; width:100vw !important; }
        .td,
        .m-shell { width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; }
        .pre-header-text,
        .mt-center { text-align: center !important; }
        .center { margin: 0 auto !important; }
        .m-td,
        .m-hide { display: none !important; width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important; font-size: 0 !important; line-height: 0 !important; min-height: 0 !important; }
        .m-block { display: block !important; }
        .fluid-img img { width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
        .column,
        .column-bottom,
        .column-top { float: left !important; width: 100% !important; display: block !important; }
        .content-spacing { width: 15px !important; }
        .pb-10 { padding-bottom: 10px !important; }
        .pb-15 { padding-bottom: 15px !important; }
        .pb-50 { padding-bottom: 50px !important; }
        .pt-15 { padding-top: 15px !important; }
        .plr-15 { padding-left: 15px !important; padding-right: 15px !important; }
        .ptb-15 { padding-top: 15px !important; padding-bottom: 15px !important; }
        .mt-0 { margin-top: 0 !important; }
        .p15-0 { padding: 15px 0 !important; }
        .p50-0 { padding: 50px 0 !important; }
        .p10-0 { padding: 10px 0 !important; }
        .p15 { padding: 15px !important; }
        .m-bg { -webkit-background-size: cover !important; background-size: cover !important; height: auto !important; background-position: left center !important; }
        .h-auto { height: auto !important; }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<body class="body" style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; background:#e3e3e3; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#e3e3e3" class="gwfw">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="m-shell">
                <tr>
                    <td class="td" style="width:600px; min-width:600px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="img p15-0" style="padding: 16px 0 16px 23px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="column pb-10" width="144" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;"> 
                                                <div class="img-center" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center;"> <a href="http://culverco.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://culverco.com/email/19029_uw_bts_email/images/logo.jpg" width="144" height="32" border="0" alt="Culver logo" /></a> </div>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>        
</body>
</html>
```

I expect all emails to be displayed within the same email, especially since they are all coded the same way and are using the same inline CSS. But, what I do see is this.

[image: this.]

Comment: How I think this works is the screenshots are taken at a specific time. This doesn't take into account when an email is fully loaded or not. I used to see the same with Litmus but now its not happening. Might be a good idea to ask EOA to see if they can shed some light on it.

Comment: ^ The above point is very valid and affects all testing tools from time to time. I would suggest finding people with the devices affected in Email on Acid and send tests to those devices. That may be tough, as people generally update their phones more frequently now, but that is your next best step.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense-- I tested some devices today so I will update the results of that when I can. Thank you both!

Comment: Results came out fine on both iphone and ipads. Must be the Email on acid tests. Thanks for the input!